# Apparent connection error with EntityFactory

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, entity, eclipselink

I am writing a small 4 table database application. Using NetBeans 7.31 used Derby 10.1.1 db and Embedded jdbc driver, JPA/EclipseLink 2.50 for building the entities, using JPAController as a wrapper for each of the entities. Had no problem building the entities or connecting to db during construction or through services in IDE. Any function sent to entity controller - Edit, Merge, Destroy, or Findall I get a NPE. Ran JUnit test's on major functions all is fine until it has to connect to DB then a NPE. persistence.xml reflects proper connection info and the classes included. I am new to this so any pointers to the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: not clear what is the problem

Comment: Can you give some code sample and a stack trace of the NPE?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at eclc.eclcshow.Main$1.run(Main.java:119)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Total time: 3.667s
Finished at: Sat Aug 10 16:09:58 EDT 2013
Final Memory: 7M/232M

Comment: Post code? Any code that requests results from the database - doesn't matter what it is. Like I said it looks like a communication error but I thought the EntityManager or EntityFactory takes care of that thru persistence

Comment: jt= pb.setjTable(ejc.findEntriesEntities(),"Entries");

Comment: PanelBuilder pb = new PanelBuilder();
EntriesJpaController ejc = null;
JTable jt = null ;

Comment: @Algorithmist the problem is -> Any function sent to entity controller - Edit, Merge, Destroy, or Findall I get a NPE.

Comment: If you want to see the code:http://dethdealers.com/backup Main.html,Entries.html,EntriesJpaController.html, ModelBuilder.html, PanelBuilder.html  Main is where I call the first query, and I also try to put data into the DB and that is the second NPE -

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception hare, and the relevant code here, by editing your question.

Comment: Its not possible to post the code here for you to see the entire picture - thats why I posted the links

Comment: Well the first thing I see that your "ejc" variable is always null (you do not initialize it nor inject it anywhere) which will result in an immediate NPE on line 102       jt = pb.setJTable(ejc.findEntriesEntities(), "Entries");

Comment: Thank You, that appears to be the problem. I am learning..